# Having problems running WebSocket for mqtt

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to replicate this [demo[image: DEMO]](https://github.com/jpmens/tempgauge)

using my own mosquitto instance to control the meter. When I try to connect to "`test.mosquitto.org", 8080` everything works great, but when I plug my own mqtt server's IP I receive: `Connection failed: AMQJ0007E Socket error:undefined.` 
I believe this is due to the requirement of a websocket service to run on the same machine as the mqtt. The original author uses WSS, and I can't figure out how to install this service (complete noob). I Even tried to follow [these directions](https://github.com/stylpen/WSS/issues/15) with no luck Could anyone give some directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest answer to this is probably to wait for Mosquitto v1.4 to ship which has baked in Websocket support.

If you can't wait for it to ship you can build from the development head stream which will get you what your looking for. You've not said what platform you are running the broker on, but these instructions should help on Linux: http://goochgooch.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/

Comment: My bad, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1. Your link seems to be a great solution. I'm going to keep the topic open for a bit longer: just in case anyone else has more to add. Thank you for the prompt response!

Answer (score 4):

You can try Installing him HiveMQ while you wait for mosquito 1.4. That is a broker with websockets built in.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I ended up building mosquitto 1.4 and, on the way, I learnt a few more new things.

Comment: review on Hive's websocket: `http://jpmens.net/2013/10/23/the-hivemq-mqtt-broker/`

Answer (score 2):

Mosquitto v1.4 has been released on February 18th, 2015. It has inbuilt support for websockets.

Comment: Thank you for keeping this thread up to date! It would be helpful to include relevant links to make others' life easier